# Remove duplicates for IMPORTRANGE based on the lowest value in another column

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, import, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting

I'm using IMPORTRANGE and in one of the columns there are duplicates. I only want to show the row from the duplicates that has the lowest value based on another column.

[image: Illustration image]

My current query:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("google.com/spreadsheets/d/x/edit","sheet name"),"Select Col1,Col4,Col7,Col5,Col15 where Col5 contains 'some text' and Col15 contains 'some other text' and Col4 is not null order by Col4 asc")
```

Based on the earlier illustration, Col4 is A and Col7 is B.

I would greatly appreciate if you could tell me how to edit the existing query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=SORTN(SORT(QUERY(
 IMPORTRANGE("google.com/spreadsheets/d/x/edit", "sheet name"), 
 "select Col1,Col4,Col7,Col5,Col15 
  where Col5  contains 'some text' 
    and Col15 contains 'some other text'  
    and Col4 is not null 
  order by Col4 asc", ), 2, 1), 9^9, 2, 1, 1)
```

---

### update:

```
=SORTN(SORT(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("id","(2) NL_ranking_file.csv!A2:O250"),
 "select Col1,Col4,Col7,Col5,Col15 
  where Col5  contains '' 
    and Col15 contains 'Places' 
    and Col4 is not null 
  order by Col4 asc", ), 3, 1), 9^9, 2, 2, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks but that wiped out all the rows in the sheet leaving only the first entry.

Comment: I blindly played with the numbers and did: "9^9, 2, 2, 1"

That got half way there by actually removing the duplicates but it didn't leave the ones with the lowest value based on Col7. It just picked the first of each.

Comment: Sure, link with editor rights is: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_qZYUTLpiadyyZE4ji6Z7CXM8LZJeE8s8vezmzf_IL4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry! Should work now.

Comment: @Mark answer updated

Comment: Amazing thank you. If you could just remove the sheet ID from your updated query, would be appreciated for privacy reasons.